# Remove platform override in Codename One Designer

Tags: codenameone, theming

How can I remove platform override in Codename One Designer? With this option do not apply common styles from [Base Resource]. It is not convenient, as common style is often changed and updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We generally don't recommend that you override the main theme since there is so much that can be broken.

We suggest creating two themes: your main theme and an override theme. The override theme should be very simple and have minimal dependencies.

Then when you initialize the theme (in the `initThemes` method for a GUI builder app) just use `setThemeProps(mainTheme)` followed by `addThemeProps(overrideTheme)`.

Comment: How can I remove Override Theme from my main .res file without changing Base Theme? This theme has a lot of settings. Because will be hard to create new .res file with this.

Comment: Just go into the specific platform and click the x there which will only remove the override without touchthing the main theme. Save then return to the main theme, the override will no longer be there.

Comment: This helps in Padding for statusBar without addThemeProps

if (Display.getInstance().getPlatformName().equals("ios")) {
            toolbar.getStyle().setPadding(Container.TOP, 15);
        }